# Cucumber-JVM with Gradle, How to fail the program if an incorrect test name is passed?

Tags: cucumber, cucumber-jvm, cucumber-java, cucumberjs, cucumber-serenity

I try to run Cucumber-JVM with Gradle with such that If I pass a test name that doesn't exist, the program will fail.
Is there a way to do this by passing an appropriate argument?

I tried playing with the arguments but I couldn't do what I wanted

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the following argument to the `build.gradle` file:

```
cucumber {
    ...
    options {
        ...
        failIfNoTests(true)
    }
}
```

Comment: it's throw an error: 
> Could not find method cucumber() for arguments on project ':cucumber-test' of type org.gradle.api.Project.

Comment: Have you added cucumber to the gradle project:
```
plugins {
    id 'java'
    id 'info.cukes.cucumber-jvm' version '1.2.6'
}

dependencies {
    testImplementation 'info.cukes:cucumber-junit:1.2.6'
    testImplementation 'info.cukes:cucumber-java:1.2.6'
}
```